# Recovering ssd data - Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ssd

I have my mother's laptop with me, a lenovo g-70. She claims she did a "windows" update (she has windows 10) and the computer will not boot up now. It was completely "fine", as far as I know the night before.

It displays the lenovo logo and goes blank. I searched online, and that seems to be an issue with the power supply / battery, so I tried the proposed solutions without success.

I wanted to install a fresh copy of win10 anyway, so I plugged this in my win10 machine, and it wouldn't allow my pc to boot. I thought it was weird, so I plugged in this sshd after my computer had already boot to windows a few times. Every time, my computer becomes somewhat unresponsive. The only partition visible on explorer is one with 8 GB, which is accessible, very, very slowly. Now, not only my computer becomes unresponsive, I can't open disk management, I can't open a partition software and I can't use the internet. The computer is connected, online, using my ssd, and somehow this secondary, just plugged in sshd makes the internet not work. I unplug it and everything is fine. All I want at this point is to try to recover her data. Any ideas?
I also used a thumbdrive with windows 10 on her pc to try to repair the disk, or install win10, but the laptop also becomes unresponsive when that sshd is plugged in, even when booting from the usb stick.
I booted very slowly using a linux live cd, and got the attached results.
The sshd appears not to be mounted, and when trying to mount it I get a reply that it is busy. Is there any hope? I do see all those bad sectors, could that message be wrong, or is this thing gone?

[image][image][image]

Comment: The next thing I would try is to put the drive in an USB enclosure.  Then, if it mounts, run AV/Malware scans on it.  If it doesn't mount, then you can still try drive recovery software, but this shouldn't prevent your computer from booting.  If you want it to be internal, you can always go into the BIOS/UEFI to specify which drive to boot from, instead of it auto-detecting the wrong drive.  If you've already tried that, back to the USB enclosure and AV scans.

Comment: @computercarguy even when booting from an usb with windows installation in it, the hard drive makes the installation freeze before it even gets past the windows logo. I'll try your suggestion as well.

Comment: You may also want to rewrite your boot sector, just in case.  I Answered another question on that front just a few minutes ago at https://superuser.com/questions/1282908/random-bootloops-with-pc-and-windows-10-possibly-bios-motherboard-related/1282928#1282928.

Comment: @computercarguy but even with an installation disc, it freezes like I said, so I can't get to this point, and besides, it makes another computer freeze when plugged in while this other computer is already on windows, so the boot may be damaged, but I don't think this is the major issue here.

Comment: Right, get the disk working first, do any AV scans you can, then rewrite the boot sector if possible.  BTW, does the disk make any odd noises, i.e. clunks, clicking patterns, growling/screeching, etc.?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. There's no visible damage to the computer or drive as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your computer becomes unresponsive whenever the suspect drive is connected is because it is failing to respond to the majority of the I/O requests made of it. When the drive doesn't respond, the storage controller subsystem waits until a timeout period expires before giving up on the request. This is made worse by the fact that the drive's partial responsiveness (as evidenced by the fact you're seeing that 8 GB partition) prompts the OS to continue sending requests to the drive, filling up the storage controller's queue with requests that will take time before they fail.

While you can keep attempting to access the drive, hoping it will behave long enough to receive your data, the odds are against that working. Whatever is ailing your drive is unlikely to suddenly work itself out. Unfortunately, data recovery isn't an option until the drive is willing to carry out the I/O requests sent to it.

If you have a backup (and you should) your best way forward is to use it. If you don't have a backup, then you should consider sending the drive to a data recovery service if the data on it is that valuable.

Comment: In your opinion, it is in fact bad, where only professionals could try to recover the data, or is there a way to try to access and recover it?

Comment: @riseagainst The answer depends on how valuable the data is to you. If it's critical that you get it back, use a professional. If you are OK with your own recovery efforts ending with loss of the data, you can try yourself. At this point though, the try yourself option most likely means buying another identical drive and swapping the electronics out...not a task for the inexperienced.

Comment: I've already swapped the drive for a different one and have the fresh system up and running. For me, personally the data has no value, but it's my mothers data, and I'd like to try and recover it to her. I know services such as these can cost thousands of dollars, so its a question whether she thinks this data is that valuable, but my question is based on the information provided along with images, is there something else I can try myself, other tools / methods or not? It just seems really sudden for (what it looks like) all those blocks go bad.

Comment: @riseagainst IMO you're out of options. It sounds like the drive has suffered a failure in its logic board, which can indeed happen suddenly. That's not an easy thing to fix on your own. A recovery service can give you a quote before you spend too much money, so it may be worth looking into.