# Random bootloops with PC and Windows 10, possibly BIOS/motherboard related

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bios

Recently, when I boot my machine, Windows 10 would get stuck on a "Preparing for startup repair" screen. This screen would stay there forever, with the "spinning loading dots" animation.

After 5 to 6 hard resets of my machine Windows would boot up quickly and properly with no errors. Some daysit would boot on the first try, and sometimes it would take up to 10 reboots.

I tried to reinstall Windows 10 from a USB stick, but even the USB stick would be stuck on a "never-ending startup" until after 4 or 5 reboots, at which point the Windows 10 installer ran properly and without any issues.

Now, after a brand new Windows 10 install on my formatted SSD, I am having the same issue - Windows still refuses to start properly, instead going into "startup repair preparation" about every 5 out of 6 times.

I was tempted to say it is a problem with the SSD, but it is strange that my machine had the same trouble booting off of the USB stick as well. 
I scanned the main Windows partition on the SSD with the "right click->scan drive for errors" feature in Windows and it found no errors.

Comment: How much time are you allowing? You need to be patient with Windows. If you interrupt it at the wrong time you can leave the system in an unbootable condition. Startup repair is triggered by a failed boot. So, if you powered off the PC while it was booting, for example. It will think that the boot failed.

Comment: The longest I had waited overall was probably an hour. I am not sure if that is insufficient time, but during that period there wouldn't be any change on the screen besides the spinning dots underneath the Windows logo.

Comment: Do you have the problem booting from your USB device *without* the SSD connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to post back here in case anyone else stumbles upon this issue while googling.

After reinstalling Windows and continuing to have boot issues, I updated my BIOS, which looks to have resolved my boot issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this may be a boot virus.  Reloading Windows may not rewrite the boot sector, if it's repairing an existing Win installation.  It may not even rewrite the boot sector if you've reinstalled on the same partition, meaning you didn't repartition the drive before the new install.

https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/

That page has instructions on how to rewrite the boot sector on several Win OSes, but here's a snippet for Win10:

> Boot from the original installation DVD (or the recovery USB)
>   At the Welcome screen, click Repair your computer
>   Choose Troubleshoot
>   Choose Command Prompt
>   When the Command Prompt loads, type the following commands:
>
> bootrec /FixMbr
>   bootrec /FixBoot
>   bootrec /ScanOs
>   bootrec /RebuildBcd
>
> Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each command and wait for each operation to finish
>   Remove the DVD (USB stick) from the disk tray
>   Type exit
>   Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
>   Restart your computer and check if Windows 10 starts

There's a 2nd part to this fix, but that's only if this doesn't work and you know it's the boot sector giving you the problem.  I'm not including that here, since it's pretty long, and hopefully Part 1 works.

This is at least the First thing I'd do, given what you've already done.

Since this is happening on your USB stick, you may want to do this on that drive, too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Something I should mention - before reinstalling windows I deleted all partitions on my SSD - I would assume that is where the boot sector is stored as well?

Comment: IIRC, the boot sector is outside any partitions.  However, if you deleted the partitions, that should have prompted any new OS installation to rewrite the boot sector.

Comment: Just to triple check - I deleted the boot partition. Is this where the MBR is stored? If so then that was all re-installed/re-created.

However one interesting thing - when I try to boot from some random media with no boot information (a blank DVD-rom, etc) there is a grub recovery console.

Comment: The boot sector and the boot partition are 2 different and separate things.  The boot sector tells the computer/BIOS/UEFI which partition is bootable.  Every disk/writable media has a boot sector, even if it doesn't have a bootable partition.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_sector  The grub recovery console may be part of your UEFI, but I'm not sure on that one.